# How to disable Magnifier widget From EditText Android

Tags: android, view, android-edittext, widget

[image]

Only need to disable Magnifier widget From EditText Android

Answer (score 0):

Magnifier is a widget and it's not a part of EditText API.
Not sure whats this context on your issue, but if you are using the Magnifier API to show it, just do not do that.

Comment: Magnifier is provided by android along with EditText. I haven't added any code for it. Only need to disable this feature. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/magnifier

Comment: They are definitely doing magnifier.show there in order to show it